# how to find sum of all first elements of several lists i got as output

Tags: python, list, data-analysis, astropy, fits

I have a got several list of numbers as output.i need to find the sum of all the corresponding first elements of all the lists(to find the average).

```
  for i in fitsfiles:
    hdul = fits.open (i)
    flux= hdul[1].data['FLUX']
    waves =hdul[1].data['WAVE']
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
    f = interp1d(waves,flux,fill_value='interpolate')
    f_int = f(w_int)
    intflux = f_int.tolist()
    print(sum(intflux[0]))
```

I interpolated the parent data and the interpolated data is the output intflux.
while doing the sum on this float im getting the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable".
Please help me how to find the average of all the corresponding elements of the list that comes as output

[this is how my output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReTbj.png)

Comment: What are the shapes of the flux and wave arrays? Are they 1-D or 2-D?

Comment: They are of 1-D

Comment: That's what I figured.  Then I'm a bit confused, what exactly do you want to average?  The total flux?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `intflux` is a specific output list (the last one generated in the loop) at any given time, rather than representing all of the output lists as a whole. Therefore `intflux[0]` is the first element of a specific output list, rather than containing the first element of every output list.

You could store a list of all output lists, but if the only information you need is the sum or average, it may be simpler just to keep a running total, and add to it after generating each list:

```python3
running_total = 0
for i in fitsfiles:
    ...
    running_total += intflux[0]
average = running_total / len(fitsfiles)
```

P.S. Try moving the line `from scipy.interpolate import interp1d` to the start of your program. This makes your code faster and much more readable.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply.i wanted to get an output in which all such columns of intflux are averaged.

Answer (score -1):

Given a list of lists `list_of_lists` such as your output, you can use a python comprehension to iterate over the items in `list_of_lists` generating the first element of each list, then call `sum()` with this comprehension as its argument:

```py
list_of_lists = [
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [2.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [3.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [4.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [5.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [6.1, 1.2, 1.3]
]

sum_of_first = sum(x[0] for x in list_of_lists)
print(sum_of_first)
```

Output:

```
21.6
```

Comment: This isn't really what the OP needs to do, and also they're working with NumPy arrays so they don't really want "lists" at all, even if that's what they wrote.

Comment: @Iguananaut Please clarify what you mean when you say OP wants something different from what they wrote, and how you know this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know it took some time.  But here they're working with numpy arrays and just want to keep a running sum of array values for the purpose of producing a mean.  There should be no lists involved as the data is already a numpy array, and there is no reason for this purpose to convert it to a list.  I know this because beginners with Python numerical data can be sometimes imprecise in wording and don't fully appreciate the difference between arrays and lists, also as one of the primary authors of the library I've helped many other researchers with similar problems.